# Как выделить ячейки в таблице разными цветами?

Tags: php, css, mysql

в БД хранится информация о цвете данной ячейки.

```
printf( '      
            <p> Выберите время приема:</p><br />
                <table width="40" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="%s">%s </td>',$myrow['value'], $myrow['time']);

 <td class="%s"> ---- думал таким способом задать класс, а в классе прописать все свойства.
```

Не работает. В чем ошибка и есть ли другие варианты реализации?

Comment: Ошибку нашел. роблема с БД была. 
А какие другие пути еще могут быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть еще вариант как покрасить столбцы:

```
.table td{background:#f00}
.table td + td{background:#0f0}
.table td + td + td{background:#00f}
```

А в вашем варианте я бы писал в БД не сами классы, а их номера, для последующей генерации классов вида .tdbg1, .tdbg2 ...